# Приложение уходит в фоновый режим и загружает процессор

Tags: c#, winui3, windows-app-sdk

Есть простое приложение WinUI 3, которое после закрытия иногда попадает в фоновый режим и загружает процессор на 20-25%. Приходится отключать его с TaskManager, чтобы можно было заново запустить. Кто-то сталкивался с этим?

Я думаю, что проблема в использовании PDF-слайдера. Когда его убираю, то приложение не уходит в фоновый режим.

```
    public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> PDFPages { get; set; } = new();
    private async void LoadPDF()
    {
        try
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(SelectedItem.Name);
            if (extension != ".pdf" && extension != ".PDF") return;

            StorageFile storagePDFFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync($@"{Folderpath}{SelectedFolder}{SelectedItem.Name}");
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(storagePDFFile);

            PDFPages.Clear();

            for (ushort i = 0; i < pdfDoc.PageCount; i++)
            {
                BitmapImage image = new();
                PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
                using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new())
                {
                    await page.RenderToStreamAsync(stream);
                    await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                }
                PDFPages.Add(image);
            }
            pdfDoc = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Message(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

```xml
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">
        <FlipView ItemsSource="{x:Bind dokumenteVM.PDFPages}" Background="Transparent">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не сталкивался, не воспроизводится на моих WinUI3 приложениях. Какую Windows App SDK версию вы используете? Используете ли многооконность, диспозите ли неуправляемые ресурсы? Без кода здесь мало чего можно сказать.

Comment: Использую последнюю версию Windows App SDK, но проблема была уже и на .net 5 Project Reunion. Код, к сожалению, не могу сюда выложить. Он очень большой. Тут не возможности связаться лично с участниками, например платный урок/консультация? У меня несколько вопросов по C# и WinUI. Я "программист"-любитель. Хотел бы с профессионалами пообщаться.

Comment: [Использование объектов, реализующих IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects). Вы где-то забываете очищать ресурсы.